# Laravel updating object from json with many parameters

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to update my object in the database from my request?

Currently I am updating every single field and then saving the object:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->username = $request->username;
$user->role = $request->role;
$user -> save();
```

Also it is not required to have all the fields present. One request can update the role of the user, but other can update only the username.

How can I loop and update only the present fields from the request or is there a way to pass the whole request as a paramater and setting only the id and eloquent to know what to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do a `foreach()` over the values in `$request` and assign them to your `$user` prior to saving:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
foreach($request->except(["_token"]) AS $key => $value){
  $user->{$key} = $value;
  // Example: $key = "username", $value = "BobSmith"; `$user->username = "BobSmith";`
}
$user->save();
```

Note: Use `$request->except()` to omit fields that are sent in the request but don't exist as columns on the `users` table, like `_token` (required in `POST` requests).

Comment: That worked thanks, but I am including a token with the header and i removed the except, but foreach($request as $key => $value) didn't work. It gave Object of class .. could not be converted to string. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh I included $request->all() and it worked is this the right way?

Comment: One of your inputs (inside of `$value`) can't be converted to a string; might need a check while looping.

Comment: @ivaylo Yes, its because `$request` is an object. But function `$request->all() or $request->except(here array of exception) or $request->only(here array of fields) ` returns array of data with you can put in forach loop. If you have `$fillable` property in your `User` object you could achieve same thing by doing this: `User::findOrFail($id)->update($request->only(['username','role']);`